# Calling C# function from a C++/CLI function

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, interop, marshalling

My project requires me to use C# to provide a user interface to C++. One of the C++ function I call does a bunch of work and provides periodic progress updates through another "object." Here's a example of what I mean.

C++

```
class AppDelegate : public ProgressDelegate
    {
    void AppDelegate::UpdateStatusText(const char* text)
        {
        // Go() will end up calling me at some point.
        OutputDebugString(text);
        }
    void AppDelegate::ShowMessage(const char* text)
        {
        // Go() will end up calling me at some point.
        OutputDebugString(text);
        }
     };

int CppWrapper::Go()
    {
    return cppInstance->Go()
    }
```

CSharp

```
void UpdateStatusText(String text)
   {
   //update UI
   }
void ShowMessage(String text)
   {
   //update UI
   }
```

What I want to do is take updateStatusText and ShowMessage and pass the text over to C# to update my UI. My question is how do I expose the appropriate C# methods so that they can be called by my C++ code? Note that modifying Go is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this example can help you:

**Write a Managed DLL**

To create a simple managed DLL that has a public method to add two numbers and return the result, follow these steps:

Start Microsoft Visual Studio .NET or Microsoft Visual Studio 2005.
On the File menu, point to New, and then click Project. The New Project dialog box opens.
Under Project Types, click Visual C# Projects.

Note In Visual Studio 2005, click Visual C# under Project Types.
Under Templates, click Class Library.
In the Name text box, type sManagedDLL, and then click OK.
Open the Class1.cs file in Code view.
To declare a public interface that has a method to add two numbers, add the following code to the Class1.cs file:

```
// Interface declaration.
public interface ICalculator
{
    int Add(int Number1, int Number2);
};
```

To implement this public interface in a class, add the following code to the Class1.cs file:

```
// Interface implementation.
public class ManagedClass:ICalculator
{
    public int Add(int Number1,int Number2)
        {
            return Number1+Number2;
        }
}
```

**Register the Managed DLL for Use with COM or with Native C++**
To use the managed DLL with COM or with native C++, you must register the assembly information of your DLL in the Windows registry. To do this, follow these steps:

**Call the Managed DLL from Native C++ Code**

```
// Import the type library.
#import "..\ManagedDLL\bin\Debug\ManagedDLL.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
```

Change the path of the type library if the path on your computer differs from this path.
To declare the namespace to use, add the following code to the CPPClient.cpp file:

```
using namespace ManagedDLL;
```

***Complete Code Listing***

```
  //Managed DLL
  // Class1.cs
  // A simple managed DLL that contains a method to add two numbers.
  using System;

  namespace ManagedDLL
  {
    // Interface declaration.
      public interface ICalculator
      {
          int Add(int Number1, int Number2);
      };

      // Interface implementation.
    public class ManagedClass:ICalculator
    {
         public int Add(int Number1,int Number2)
              {
                  return Number1+Number2;
              }
    }
  }


  //C++ Client
  // CPPClient.cpp: Defines the entry point for the console application.
  // C++ client that calls a managed DLL.

  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include "tchar.h"
  // Import the type library.

  #import "..\ManagedDLL\bin\Debug\ManagedDLL.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
  using namespace ManagedDLL;
  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {
      // Initialize COM.
      HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

      // Create the interface pointer.
      ICalculatorPtr pICalc(__uuidof(ManagedClass));

      long lResult = 0;

      // Call the Add method.
      pICalc->Add(5, 10, &lResult);

      wprintf(L"The result is %d\n", lResult);


      // Uninitialize COM.
      CoUninitialize();
      return 0;
  }
```

Reference:
[How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code in Visual Studio.NET or in Visual Studio 2005](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736)

Comment: Why it is needed the interface class? Can a regular class be accessed?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, what I used to do (before I switched to using P/Invoke method to call from C# to C++) was to have 3 projects (as StraightLine has mentioned) but I'd have C#, Managed C++, and Native C++, and have the Managed C++ be my bridge/proxy to talk between the two (Native C++ and C#).  It made it more easier to work on my Native C++ side that way.  One caution is that some of the STL (mostly containers) are not supported by managed or sometimes, behaviors of std::string (Managed C++ version) would cause exceptions when used in Native C++ std::string, so do pay attention to which STL libraries are Managed C++ supported.

Also, as StraightLine has mentioned, the bridged code (in my case, Manaaged C++) would have to have a wrapper which will marshal from Managed to Native and vice versa (i.e. your "const char*" to System.String, if your char is 8-bits, etc)

Comment: How did you call from C++ into C# inside your setup? You must be building the C# project to an executable, and not a library. How then do you reference it from elsewhere? OP says that his GUI is in C#, so he ought to build his C# code into an executable

Answer (score 0):

You would have to build relevant C# code into an assembly, then reference that assembly inside C++ CLI project. Inside your C++ CLI wrapper, you will make calls to functions exposed through this C# assembly, also you will make calls into native C++ code.

The C++ CLI project can contain native C++ code, just make sure that the CLR switch is not enabled for native files. So, you would have 3 projects -

1. C# project for GUI which will invoke main. Also references the assembly used to expose C# functions to be called via C++ interop.
2. C# assembly that exposes certain managed functions (thus callable from C++ CLI)
3. C++ CLI project which will wrap and also contain native code.